# How to convert an object in vue back into a standard js object?

Tags: vue.js

Is there a function to convert objects that have be converted into vuejs's reactive system back into a normal object?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't. The question is why do you need to convert them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try:
`const normalObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectWithReactivity))`.

Answer (score 0):

Even try a copy using ecmascript

```
object_reactive
let object = {...object_reactive}
```

or maybe just javascript

```
var obj = { a: 1 };
var copy = Object.assign({}, obj);
```